# Is there any way to place buttons according to a central point in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

this is what I am trying to do:

[image]

Is anyone know how can i do it in swift?
I know there are some libraries that do something similar but I am trying to do it myself

Comment: a combination of GeometryReader and position (or offset) should let you do that.

Comment: Are you using Swift or SwiftUI? Several of the suggested solutions (Like using `GeometryReader` or `.position(x:,y:)` are SwiftUI-specific. My answer shows you how to arrange your buttons in a circle in regular Swift.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something like that with `UICollectionView` and custom `UICollectionViewLayout`

Some examples:

- https://www.raywenderlich.com/1702-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-a-spinning-wheel
- https://augmentedcode.io/2019/01/20/circle-shaped-collection-view-layout-on-ios/
- https://github.com/robertmryan/CircularCollectionView

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Set up constraints with offsets from your center point, and use trig to calculate the offsets. The code might look something like this:

```
let steps = 16     // The number of buttons you want
let radius = 75.0. // Your desired circle radius, in points
let angleStep = Double.pi * 2.0 / Double(steps)
for index in 0 ..< steps {
    let angle = Double(index) * angleStep
    let xOffset = CGFloat(radius * cos(angle))
    let yOffset = CGFloat(radius * sin(angle))
    // add button to superview with center anchored to center of superview 
    // offset by xOffset and yOffset
}
```

### Edit:

I mostly create my views and controls using storyboards, so this was a good excuse to practice creating them in code. I made a demo project on github that creates a circle of buttons. You can download it here:

https://github.com/DuncanMC/ButtonsInCircle.git

All the logic is in the View controller's source file:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  ButtonsInCircle
//
//  Created by Duncan Champney on 2/28/21.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonContainerView: UIView!

    let buttonCount = 12 //The number of buttons to create
    var angleStep: Double = 0 //The change in angle between buttons

    var radius: CGFloat = 75.0  // The radius to use (will be updated at runtime based on the size of the container view.)

    //A type to hold a layout anchor for a button, it's index, and whether it's a horizontal or veritical anchor
    typealias ConstraintTuple = (index: Int, anchor: NSLayoutConstraint, axis: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis)

    //An array of the layout anchors for our buttons.
    var constraints = [ConstraintTuple]()

    //Our layout has changed. Update the array of layout anchors
    func updateButtonConstraints() {

            for (index, constraint, axis) in self.constraints {
                let angle = Double(index) * self.angleStep
                let xOffset = self.radius * CGFloat(cos(angle))
                let yOffset = self.radius * CGFloat(sin(angle))
                if axis == .horizontal {
                    constraint.constant = xOffset
                } else {
                    constraint.constant = yOffset
                }
            }
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        //Pick a radius that's a little less than 1/2 the shortest side of our bounding rectangle
        radius = min(buttonContainerView.bounds.width, buttonContainerView.bounds.height) / 2 - 30
        print("Radius = \(radius)")
        updateButtonConstraints()
    }

    func createButtons() {
        for index in 0 ..< buttonCount {

            //Create a button
            let button = UIButton(primaryAction:
                                    //Define the button title, and the action to trigger when it's tapped.
                                    UIAction(title: "Button \(index+1)") { action in
                                        print("Button \(index + 1) tapped")
                                    }
            )
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //Remember to do this for UIViews you create in code
            button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0  // Draw a rounded rect around the button so you can see it
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 5

            button.setTitle("\(index+1)", for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)

            //Add it to the container view
            buttonContainerView.addSubview(button)
            button.sizeToFit()

            //Create center x & y layout anchors (with no offset to start)
            let buttonXAnchor = button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonContainerView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0)
            buttonXAnchor.isActive = true

            //Add a tuple for this layout anchor to our array
            constraints.append(ConstraintTuple(index: index, anchor: buttonXAnchor, axis: .horizontal))

            let buttonYAnchor =  button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonContainerView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0)
            buttonYAnchor.isActive = true

            //Add a tuple for this layout anchor to our array
            constraints.append(ConstraintTuple(index: index, anchor: buttonYAnchor, axis: .vertical))
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        angleStep = Double.pi * 2.0 / Double(buttonCount)
        createButtons()
    }


}
```

It looks like this when you run it:

[image]

(On iOS, the starting angle (0°) is "East" in terms of a compass. If you want your first button to start at the top you'd have to add an offset to your starting angle.)

Comment: Note that the answer above places your buttons in a full circle around the center of their containing view. Your sample image shows your buttons in a quarter-circle arc, centered on the bottom right corner of their containing view. It wouldn't be too hard to adapt the code above to arrange buttons in a part-circle arc, and centered on a corner of a view rather than the center.

Comment: Another note: The code above is using a cool new addition to UIKit in iOS 14: The ability to create buttons using closures with the UIButton initializer `UIButton.init(primaryAction:UIAction)`

Answer (score 1):

## SwiftUI

You can position any view anywhere using either `offset(x: y)` or `position(x:y)`.

#### offset(x:y:)

> Offset this view by the specified horizontal and vertical distances. - [https://developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu/offset(x:y:))

#### position(x:y:)

> Positions the center of this view at the specified coordinates in its
> parent’s coordinate space.[https://developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu/position(x:y:))

For instance:

```
    ZStack {
        Text("A")
            .background(Color.red)
            .position(x: 10, y: 20)
        
        Text("b")
            .background(Color.red)
            .position(x: 50, y: 30)
        
        Text("c")
            .background(Color.red)
            .position(x: 100, y: 40)
        Text("d")
            .background(Color.red)
            .position(x: 150, y: 200)
    }
```

*Find the exact x and y position yourself*

---

Fore more info, read this articel
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/absolute-positioning-for-swiftui-views

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about SwiftUI in their question. They asked about Swift, not SwiftUI. You might want to add an "If you switched to SwiftUI..." preamble to your answer.

Comment: Also, I gather from the question that they don't know how to calculate positions in a circle. You did not address that part at all.